# Сползают слова, помогите

Tags: css, html5, css3

[image: Ребята, кто знает в чем проблема, как сделать так, чтоб "слуха и речи" не прижимались к картинке?]

Ребята, кто знает в чем проблема, как сделать так, чтоб "слуха и речи" не прижимались к картинке?

[image: Теперь так]
Теперь так

- Лор
- Сурдолог
- Сурдопедагог
- Логопед
- Невролог
- Слухопротезист
- Реабилитация для пациентов с нарушением слуха и речи
- Офтальмолог
- Физиолечение
- Массаж

```
.med-wrap
    img
        float: left
        width: 200px
        max-width: 90%  
    ul
        list-style-type: none
        padding-top: 0px
        li
            font-size: 16px
            a
                color: #535353
                margin-left: 27px
                .fa
                    color: $grc
                    margin-right: 8px
```

Comment: Позиционируйте изображение для списка через псевдоэлементы https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/r7bdfvLz/

Comment: линии улетают за картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Может быть ширина блока, если страница разделена на них.
2. Позиционирование возможно.
3. добавьте отступ от картинки(чтоб отодвинуть список)

и отредактируйте сообщение, добавив сюда стили, без них разобраться не выйдет.

Добавляю..
никогда не ставьте для img width:200px, это свойство должно быть у блока или элемента в котором непосредственно хранится img. 
Свойства для img всегда должны быть такими:

```
width:100%;
max-width:100%;(или сколько там нужно)
```

Comment: Добавил стили, посмотрите пожалуйста :)

Comment: @YourDeveloper вы не совсем их добавили, где все те классы, которым заданы стили...

Comment: ситуация немного изменилась, а как теперь "нарушением ... "сдивнуть, чтоб четко под текстом было ?

Comment: Сделать вот эту зеленую линию псевдоэлементом. Потому что "нарушением" переносится на следующую строку, и становится в Ее начало. А верхняя строк начинается с элемента списка,  и только потом идёт сам текст.

Comment: А чтоб линии не улетали, нужно разобраться с позиционированием (position)

Comment: Если используете псевдоэлементы, не нужно туда писать иконки, рисуйте их с помощью width, Height, background (цвет) . Дальше - пользуйтесь добавлением кода через jsfiddle, я хочу вам помочь, но не хочу создавать проект с нуля. Так собственно хотят все участники форума.

Comment: И не забывайте голосовать за ответы.

Comment: Разобрался, но у бефоре сейчас left стоит около 240px это нормально ?

Comment: Да , но не забывайте, что если вы верстаете адаптивно, то нужно начинать с мобильной версии, заканчивать для декстопной, пробуйте растягивать , уменьшать окно просмотра, чтоб понять как будет выглядеть на экранах устройства ваша верстка

Comment: Я просто считал, что это неправильно когда, под каждое разрешение отступ свой прописывается, большое спасибо, а еще зачем мы для li указываем position: relative, а для бефоре absolute ?

Comment: честно скажу - лучше заново с чистой головой переписать код. Relative указывается для родительского элемента , absolute - для дочернего.

Comment: я понимаю, что для родительского и для дочернего, но что дает релейтив у родительского? А зачем переписывать, всё встало и адаптивность настроил. Можно было проще всё решить ?

Comment: Всегда можно найти решение проще ) если работает , то хорошо) в каком плане что даёт для родительского ?

Answer (score 0):

Дайте родительскому блоку,содержащиму блоки с картинкой и списком display:flex;

```
#parent{display:flex}    

<div id="parent">
  <div><img ... /></div>
  <div><ul> ...</ul></div>
</div>
```